# Extracting specific rows in an edge-list

Tags: awk

I have a large network file with millions of *undirected edges*:
**edge.txt** with *node 1*, *node 2* and some *numerical attributes*

```
a   b   0.8
b   c   0.1
d   f   0.7
e   f   0.5
c   b   0.1
b   a   0.8
a   c   0.1
```

Given another file **input.txt**

```
a
b
c
```

Only those edges should be printed which have both nodes (node1 and node2) in **input.txt**

```
a   b   0.8
b   c   0.1
a   c   0.1
```

I tried:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]++;next}{if ($1 in a && $2 in a) {print}}' input.txt edge.txt
```

Need some suggestions ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@oliv's method is the right approach but if you want to remove the transposed pairs you need to add some more conditions

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=1; next} a[$1] && a[$2] && !b[$1,$2]++ && !b[$2,$1]++' input edge

a   b   0.8
b   c   0.1
a   c   0.1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this `awk` script:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($1 in a)&&($2 in a)' input.txt edge.txt
```

The array lookup needs to be enclosed inside parenthesis, and there is no need for the `print` statement (as this is the default statement when the condition is valid).

Answer (score 1):

Another one which tries to minimize the lookups to the hash `b`, if edge >> input:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR && !($1 in a) {   # if node not in hash a yet, ie. remove duplicates in input
    for(i in a) {         # "c" -> a[]: insert to b: ca, ac, cb, bc
        b[$1 i]
        b[i $1]
    }
    a[$1]                 # new entries go to a as well
    next
}
($1 $2 in b) {
    # delete b[$1 $2]     # uncomment these to remove duplicates
    # delete b[$2 $1]     # ie. "a b 0.8" vs. "b a 0.8"
    print
}' input edge  # if both $1 and $2 are in a, $1 $2 is in b
```

output:

```
a   b   0.8
b   c   0.1
c   b   0.1
b   a   0.8
a   c   0.1
```

With the duplicates removed:

```
a   b   0.8
b   c   0.1
a   c   0.1
```